# How to check if database Sequencer is in sync with the highest current value in the database records

Tags: sql, oracle, liquibase

I need to determine if the current value of a Sequencer is in sync with the highest value of a specific ID column. For example:

```
Records | ID
-------------
record1   1
record2   2
record3   7
record4   13
```

If the sequencer has a CURRVAL of 13, then PASS
If the sequencer has a CURRVAL of anything else ( like 1, 5, or 18 ), then FAIL

The way I want to do this is to compare the max(ID) with the SEQ.CURRVAL, but the code below doesn't work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS n
FROM "MY_SCHEMA"."MY_TABLE" p
WHERE "MY_SCHEMA"."MY_SEQUENCE".CURRVAL = max(p.id);
```

If everything is in sync, I should receive a value of "1"
Otherwise, a failure is a value of "0"

The code fails with the following error:

```
ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here
00934. 00000 -  "group function is not allowed here"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 62
```

I have also tried the code below:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS n
FROM "LOGMODGCSS_DATA"."SUFFIX_ITEMS" p
HAVING "LOGMODGCSS_DATA"."SUFFIX_ITEMS_SEQ".CURRVAL = max(id);
```

Using the HAVING clause, I can get around the first error, but know I have the following error:

```
ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here
02287. 00000 -  "sequence number not allowed here"
*Cause:    The specified sequence number (CURRVAL or NEXTVAL) is inappropriate
           here in the statement.
*Action:   Remove the sequence number.
Error at Line: 3 Column: 45
```

Is there a way to achieve this with regular SQL, preferably a one-liner?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can do it at all, not one-line query, not multi-line, and not PL/SQL. I'd like to see a demo that proves me wrong (which would mean that I'd learn something new).

Here's why I think what I said.

First of all, you can't select current sequence value unless it is *initialized* in current session.

I have a test table (containing some IDs) and a sequence named SEQ.

Last ID value:

```
SQL> select max(id) From test;

   MAX(ID)
----------
        10
```

"Last" sequence value:

```
SQL> select seq.currval from dual;
select seq.currval from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-08002: sequence SEQ.CURRVAL is not yet defined in this session


SQL>
```

It means that you first have to select `nextval` so that you'd select `currval`, but - you already know it (that's the `nextval` you've just selected, isn't it?):

```
SQL> select seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
        27

SQL> select seq.currval from dual;

   CURRVAL
----------
        27

SQL>
```

However, it means that you've already spoiled sync between table and sequence because you used sequence value, and didn't do anything with the table itself, so it was **you** who did it, just by checking sequence value.

Besides, error you got is related to invalid usage of the aggregate (max) function - you should've put it into the `having` clause (but that's invalid as well):

```
SQL> select count(*)
  2  from test
  3  having max(id) = (select seq.nextval from dual);
having max(id) = (select seq.nextval from dual)
                             *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here


SQL>
```

If you thought of using data dictionary, you could have:

```
SQL> select last_number from user_sequences where sequence_name = 'SEQ';

LAST_NUMBER
-----------
         43

SQL>
```

That's way beyond current value - I believe that's because of caching (which can be set when creating a sequence, but in vain because of what I already described - selecting `nextval` would spoil it).

If you thought of PL/SQL:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare
  2    l_max_id test.id%type;
  3    l_seq    number;
  4  begin
  5    select max(id) into l_max_id from test;
  6    select seq.nextval into l_seq from dual;
  7
  8    if l_max_id = l_seq then
  9       dbms_output.put_line('Max ID = ' || l_max_id ||', SEQ = ' || l_seq || ' - match');
 10    else
 11       dbms_output.put_line('Max ID = ' || l_max_id ||', SEQ = ' || l_seq || ' - no match');
 12    end if;
 13  end;
 14  /
Max ID = 10, SEQ = 29 - no match

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

*Perhaps* you could fetch the sequence, compare it to max ID value stored in table, and then alter sequence to *decrease* its value so that it would look like nothing happened. However, that might be OK if it is only you who use that sequence. What if there are many users, all of them inserting many rows, and there's a database trigger that sets the `ID` value? It would become *impossible* to correctly set the last sequence value. Nightly job? Maybe, can't tell.

---

On the other hand, why do you care? Sequences will make sure that you have unique values. There might (and probably will) be gaps because you might select `nextval`, insert into a table and then **rollback** - you'd use sequence value and you're out of sync at the same moment. Perhaps you should just accept that you can't affect it.

---

**[EDIT]**

If you worry that sequence will cause duplicates if table already contains value that sequence didn't reach yet, **fix the sequence** - it is easy.

I inserted larger `ID` into the table to illustrate it:

```
SQL> select max(id) From test;

   MAX(ID)
----------
       500

SQL> select seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
        30
```

Increment sequence for a difference of MAX ID and the last sequence value (500 - 30 = 470):

```
SQL> alter sequence seq increment by 470;

Sequence altered.

SQL> select seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
       500
```

Set it to increment by 1, and you're done:

```
SQL> alter sequence seq increment by 1;

Sequence altered.

SQL> select seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
       501

SQL>
```

Comment: The reason I'm interested is because I was lead to believe that if I have collisions with the SEQ value and a pre-existing ID number, then I will receive errors. Is that true?
Like, if the CURRVAL = 4 and I already have ID values in the database of 4,5,6,7 then will the SEQ be smart enough to skip those values until it reaches 8 ?
Or is that something that I need to program?

Comment: For reasons I can't get into here, I can't assume that all the databases are in sync and can't assume that the highest ID is the same across all of them. 
I'm trying to write a script that dynamically figures out if there is a problem, and fixes it. You're solution is fine IF i was able to check and execute these commands on each database individually. Sadly, that is not realistic

Comment: @Achiral - It is unrealistic to expect to be able to detect and resolve a problem in database A without connecting to database A.  You could certainly automate that process (i.e. write a program that connects to each database, runs a script, and then connects to the next database) but you'd need to connect to each one.   It sounds, though, like you don't actually need to know if they are equal, you just want to check that the `nextval` of the sequence is larger than the largest value currently in the table.  That should a relatively simple change to the PL/SQL script

Comment: @JustinCave, I understand completely, and apologize if my comments made you assume otherwise.
I completely realize that there will need to be a database connect. We execute all changes like these through deployment scripts, so yes....

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment, i had a similar requirement. For an application i had to copy 1-2 times per year the PRODUCTION data of some tables to the TEST system. Afterwards the Sequence-values of the TEST system were not in "sync" with the data in the tables. So i had to develop a PL/SQL script that was checking the highest values of the table(s) against the current-values of the sequence. Afterwards the sequence was dynamically "altered" to be in "sync" again.